# Bootstrap 3 column layout with minimal additional div/row markup

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to have a 3 column layout, and semantically my markup makes sense from a content point of view:

```
<!-- 1. main-->
<div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
  <div class="product"></div>
</div>
<!-- 2. side bar -->
<div>
</div>
<!-- 3. other info -->
<div>
</div>
```

I am looking to style the below layout of the main column containing a sub 2 column layout of products, and the sidebar, along with other div at the bottom of the page:

[image: layout]

I have created some bootstrap code and have the following questions:

1. When the below code is ran, why is the `other` div at the end offset to the left and how do i fix this?
2. Ideally i want to keep the html as clean as possible (not adding arbitrary rows/columns) but what is the cleanest way to make the product divs stack side by side 2-wide (equal width each), and collapse on top of one another when the browser width reduces?

Code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Untitled 1</title>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <style type="text/css">

    div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <h1></h1>
        <div class='navbar navbar-inverse'>
          <div class='navbar-inner nav-collapse' style="height: auto;">
            <ul class="nav">
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id='content' class='row-fluid'>
            <div id='main' class='span9'>
                <h2>Main</h2>
                <div class="product">
                    <p>Item 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="product">
                    <p>Item 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="product">
                    <p>Item 3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="product">
                    <p>Item 4</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id='sidebar' class='span3'>
                <h2>Side</h2>
            </div>
            <div id='other' class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <p>other details here</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if http://www.bootply.com/64966 is close to what you are after. I put each pair of product divs inside nested rows ([more about fluid nesting here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem)).

Good luck!

```
<div class="container">
    <h1></h1>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="navbar-inner nav-collapse" style="height: auto;">
        <ul class="nav">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="row-fluid">
        <div id="main" class="span9">
            <h2>Main</h2>
          <div class="row-fluid"> <!-- start nested row -->
            <div class="product span6">
                <p>Item 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="product span6">
                <p>Item 2</p>
            </div>
          </div> <!-- end nested row -->

          <div class="row-fluid"> <!-- start nested row -->
            <div class="product span6">
                <p>Item 3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="product span6">
                <p>Item 4</p>
            </div>
            </div> <!-- end nested row -->
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar" class="span3">
            <h2>Side</h2>
        </div>
</div> <!-- close row-fluid -->

        <div id="other" class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <p>other details here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That is perfect @David thank you, one comment is how to minimize the markup classes with span6, span12 etc, is there any way to seperate this layout concern in to a different .css (or as complete newby i think there is a .less) file?

Comment: If you are asking because you want to reduce the CSS file size, use the bootstrap minimised CSS. If you are wondering how to seperate custom CSS from the default Boostrap CSS, you may be able to achieve the layout you want without any customisation, my CSS edits are mainly for illustration only. If you are wondering for other custom styling, creating a custom.css stylesheet that you call after the Bootstrap CSS is one easy option. Less is optional but brilliant. If you have time to get up to speed with it you will be well rewarded in the future for all CSS projects, not just Bootstrap.

Comment: Hi David, no i mean how to reduce the non-semantic markup such as rows/divs/containers etc. I will gladly take the hit on including these classes although something doesnt fit quite right with me. For CSS itself i am quite OK with, infact I use selectors a lot to minimise classes, and now with Bootstrap seems have a lot more classes now than i am used to :)

Comment: Thanks for the extra info @g18c, see if this link gets you started: http://verraes.net/2012/11/semantic-html-with-twitter-bootstrap/